# django queryset to query the latest revision only

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

If have two django models: one storing pages and an other the corresponding content revisions. Now if I search for a term I only want to consider the latest revision of each page.

```
from django.db import models

class SlugPage(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField('slug', unique = True,  max_length=255)

    @property
    def current(self):
        return self.revisions.latest()

class Revision(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(SlugPage, related_name='revisions')
    content = models.TextField('content', blank = True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField('modified', auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-modified']
        get_latest_by = 'modified'
```

I experimented a lot with django querysets, but I ended up with such python statement eventually.

```
search_term = "some text to look for"        
pages = [page for page in SlugPage.objects.all() if search_term in page.current.content]
```

Still I wonder if there is a more django-like solution as this is a frequently recurring pattern.

The solution I present in the next line solves the problem only partially. Though it lists only the latest revision it does so even if search_term is already removed from it in an earlier revision.

```
from django.db.models import Max 
pages = SlugPage.objects.annotate(Max('revisions__modified')).filter(revisions__content__icontains = search_term)
```

Comment: What is what you want? order by revisions modified? I don't understand quite well

Comment: There's an app for that. Name is [reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion). Might be a bit overkill, but if you are trying to juggle versions of something, you might want to use other features like reverting back to any state in the past/future and so on.

Comment: Thank you for considering my question. Sorry for being not explicit enough.
@Paulo I get exactly what I want in the second code block. I'd like to learn about a solution by a django queryset if it exists at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to traverse it via `SlugPage` you could do this.

```
return self.revisions_set.filter(content__icontains=search_term).latest('modified')
```

And this will get you all the `Revision` objects that matches the `.filter()` and the latest by the `modified` field.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I'm afraid this is not the answer I'm looking for. Anyway, it might be helpful to further think in that direction. Your query-set will probably filter all revisions, but I want only the most recent revisions filtered. Something like "current_set" if it were possible.